# Which Rails plug in is best for role based permissions? (Please provide one nomination per answer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to add role based permissions to my Rails application, and am wondering what the best plugins out there are to look into.  I am currently using the RESTful authentication plugin to handle user authentication.  Why is the plug in you suggest better than the other ones out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use, and really like, role_requirement:
http://code.google.com/p/rolerequirement/

Answer (score 4):

Ive got to recommended easy_roles. Its super light weight, and doesn't require extra tables etc etc.

http://github.com/platform45/easy_roles

http://gemcutter.org/gems/easy_roles

But role authentication is definitely site dependent. Different role authorization plugins suit different sites.

If you dont feel easy_roles suits your needs, check out:

http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization.html

Answer (score 0):

We've put role_requirement into [Bort](http://github.com/fudgestudios/bort/tree/master) too, as it's probably the best solution out there at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a very satisfied user of ACL

http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/acl_system

do try it!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Rails Authorization](http://blog.gingertech.net/2008/05/21/rails-authorization-plugin/) which will work with Restful Authentication quite nicely.