# (Ruby,Rails) Role-based authentication and user management...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I'm looking for a quality Administrative plugin for Rails.  It seems that most of the existing plugins/gems (e.g. "restful_authentication", "acts_as_authenticated") revolve around self-signup, etc.  However, I'm looking for a full-featured Administrative/Management role-based type of solution -- but not one that's simply tacked on to another non-role-based solution.

If I can't find one, I suppose I'll roll my own...just wasn't looking to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few out there. I have used:
http://github.com/DocSavage/rails-authorization-plugin/ for applications before in conjunction with restufl_authentication, but I believe it will work with any authentication that gives you a current_user method. On github there is also http://github.com/mdarby/restful_acl/ and http://github.com/danryan/role_model/, they are just role based stuff though I'd say not authentication as well.

The authentication and the access control role based stuff are all available as seperate plugins/gems to the best of my knowledge, and that's a good thing as they are different beasts. Not all apps that have authentication need to have ACL type stuff and even some that do only need a really simple am I an admin kind of thing rather than a full blown user roles thing. So I'd say if you want one that does it all you'll have to write, if you don't want to do that than I'd say a combination of either Authlogic or restful_authentication with on of the authorization plugins will do the trick quite nicely.

Comment: The link for restful_cal has changed to:
[https://github.com/protectedmethod/restful_acl](https://github.com/protectedmethod/restful_acl)

Answer (score 6):

Ryan Bates has recently made two railscasts on authorization (note the difference between authentication and authorization; authentication checks if a user is who she says she is, authorization checks if the user has access to a resource). [Episode #188](http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization) is on declarative_authorization, which is a really powerful authorization plugin. Episode #192 (sorry, I don't have enough reputation to link to it) is about Ryan Bates' own CanCan plugin, which is a much simpler plugin, but it would still work for most apps.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out the links in "[Which Rails plug in is best for role based permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79438/which-rails-plug-in-is-best-for-role-based-permissions-please-provide-one-nomin/79467)".

None of the solutions listed there seem very appealing to me. The top contender, [role_requirement](http://code.google.com/p/rolerequirement/) apparently requires restful_authentication, but I find [AuthLogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/tree/master) much better designed and less intrusive. The others listed seem to not be very actively maintained.